# How auto click hyperlink based on dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want a particular link to be clicked when i select a specific option in dropdown list

i've tried

```
$('#OTST').change(function () {
    if ($('#OTST').val() == "2")
        {
            $("#STSelectedPhase0").trigger('click');
        }
        else if ($('#OTST').val() == "3")
        {
            $("#OTSelectedPhase0").trigger('click');
        }
        else
        {
            $("#AllSelectedPhase0").trigger('click');
        }
});
```

also tried

```
 $("#AllSelectedPhase0").click();
```

but none of this worked

here is my code for links

```
@Html.EncodedActionLink("All", "TimeReportingDetails", "TimeReporting", new { companyId = Tlitem.CompanyId, companyWeekEnding = Tlitem.WeekEnding, FileId = Tlitem.FileId, jobId = Tlitem.JobId, jobType = Tlitem.JobType, phaseno = 0, OTST = "" }, new { Id = "AllSelectedPhase0" });

@Html.EncodedActionLink("ST", "TimeReportingDetails", "TimeReporting", new { companyId = Tlitem.CompanyId, companyWeekEnding = Tlitem.WeekEnding, FileId = Tlitem.FileId, jobId = Tlitem.JobId, jobType = Tlitem.JobType, phaseno = 0, OTST = 2 }, new { Id = "STSelectedPhase0" });

@Html.EncodedActionLink("OT", "TimeReportingDetails", "TimeReporting", new { companyId = Tlitem.CompanyId, companyWeekEnding = Tlitem.WeekEnding, FileId = Tlitem.FileId, jobId = Tlitem.JobId, jobType = Tlitem.JobType, phaseno = 0, OTST = 3 }, new { Id = "OTSelectedPhase0" });
```

and the code for dropdown is :

```
  <select id = "OTST"  class = "form-control js-select " name="OTST"  >
         <option value="0" selected="selected">All</option>
         <option value="2">ST</option>
         <option value="3">OT</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/ it should helps you

Comment: or use like `$("#STSelectedPhase0")[0].click()` in your `change` event

Comment: that works @LaljiDhameliya Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is issue with you are trigger event click but actually it return your element.
when you see `$("#STSelectedPhase0").trigger('click')` or `$("#STSelectedPhase0").click()` both returns your element `.

for auto click hyperlink you should use `$("#STSelectedPhase0")[0].click()`

```js
$("#btngoogle").click(function(){
$("#alink")[0].click()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="alink" href="https://www.google.com">Test</a>
<input id="btngoogle" type="button" value="Google">
```

i have put code on button click trigger `href`.

let me know if require more information. :)